# Sorting Cross-Tab columns in Crystal Reports with string datatype

Tags: .net, sorting, c#-4.0, sql-server-2014, crystal-reports-8.5

I am getting my column values from database as varchar datatype as a Stored procedure output. The results from database are sorted as required (in ascending order). But when i add it to Crystal reports cross tab, the sorting does not happen.

[image]

The desired result is

Pax 1-5 , 6-10, 11-15

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be sorted correctly because the field is varchar. If you create a formula that creates the sort order in the correct order it will fix this.

Comment: Can you help me to create formula for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

```
If pax = “1-5” then 1

      If pax = “6-10” then 2

             If pax = “11-15” then 3

 End
```

Since I don’t know your exact columns and fields, this formula is similar to what you should do. You can sort the groups by this formula field.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but these paxbands are coming from database based on user input. they can be anything. so i cannot define a formula.

Comment: Can you show more of your columns, fields, parameters, and such?

Comment: hey @SMcHugh, I think i found the solution for this and i will be posting it soon. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.